# kCVPixelBufferHeightKey and width not working

Tags: swift, swift5, avcapturesession, avcapturevideodataoutput

Is there a way to set a custom AVCaptureVideoDataOutput for a desired output setting. What Im trying to achieve is below. However the buffer width and height never change .What Im trying to achieve is a custom height and a width for the video pixel output. What am I missing ?

```
   AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA),
                                          kCVPixelBufferHeightKey: 300,
                                          kCVPixelBufferWidthKey: 300] as [String : Any]
```

Thus, I tried with the same objective with the session preset, but they are not capable of setting a custom width and height. **If I can get a 300x300 output thats a win**

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any change in video dimensions use [Presets](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/preset)

if it doesn't fit your need use this  [NextLevelSessionExporter](https://github.com/NextLevel/NextLevelSessionExporter)

to resize the video with or without aspect fit of the original record dimensions

Comment: Im intend not to use 3rd parties, is there a way to override kCVPixelBufferHeightKey